# Add a 256x256 icon to support top sites in Firefox

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, firefox, favicon

Currently, Firefox shows only a screenshot of the Stack Overflow page, if it's added to the top sites in the Firefox start page (in contrast to HN).

[image: Screenshot Top Sites in Firefox with the missing icon for Stack Overflow]

**Can this be fixed?**

It's really easy to do so and should only cost minimal effort. I know it's only a cosmetic change/gadget, but for regular Firefox/Stack Overflow users the site would present itself a lot prettier than before.

What it should look like:

[image: Screenshot Top Sites in Firefox with an icon for Stack Overflow]

Already one single line of code does the job:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" sizes="256x256" href="icon.png">
```

Comment: I fear adding this would be the tip of a very large iceberg. Check out [this long list of various site icons](https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet) - which doesn't even mention a 256 pixel version for Firefox.

Comment: On the other hand, I can't see that `<meta>` tag in Hacker News either, I think they just have larger sizes embedded in [their favicon.ico](https://news.ycombinator.com/favicon.ico), which might be easier to do, at the cost of a larger download for users who never see the larger version.

Comment: @IMSoP With the payload of the StackOverflow site I don't think some additional icons would hurt. On HN they added exactly that meta tag (just ommiting the type and sizes attributes). I think it works because their (only) favicon is just big enough with 256x256 pixels.

Comment: I see the logo in the Top Sites in Firefox version 60.6.3esr

Comment: [I see it too on FF Quantum 67.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5rAa.png)...

Comment: @Emaro My point was that there are literally dozens of different image sizes and markups for special cases in different browsers. The HN example is interesting, because without the `type` and `sizes` attributes, that's just the standard `meta` tag for a favicon, which SO already has. Also note that `.ico` files are containers for multiple bitmaps, so it's not necessarily that their `favicon.ico` *is* 256x256, it's just that it *contains* a 256x256 bitmap.

Comment: No repo for SO or CR - however repo for Anime & Manga. FF 67.0.2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TEmE.png

Comment: @TrebledJ That Gmail though -___-

Comment: What is your Firefox version? It works for me with Firefox Quantum 60.7.0esr (32-bit) as well and I don't really remember it not showing icon any recently.

Comment: I can repro in FF 67.0.2 (64bit), but I remember seeing just the icon from time to time as well...

Comment: I have a varied experience. EL&U's icon is full size, but SO's is as in the OP.

Comment: I tested it again and it worked. It seems pretty inconsistent. Not sure if this is a Firefox or StackOverflow issue...